# Wpf Numeric datagrid column user control editing error

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I want to create Numeric text box in datagrid user control. I have created using below code andf it is working fine.
My problem is when I type grid numeric cell allows first key alphabet, then it restricts alphabet and allows only digits.

In WGrid XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Class="WpfGrid.WGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfGrid"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" Width="500" PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" BeginningEdit="DataGrid_BeginningEdit" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False">
```

```
namespace WpfGrid
{
  public partial class WGrid : DataGrid
  {

    public WGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  }
  public class DataGridNumericColumn : DataGridTextColumn
  {
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(System.Windows.FrameworkElement editingElement, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox edit = editingElement as TextBox;
        edit.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }
    void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = new Regex("[^0-9.]").IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
  }
}
```

After Creating this control I added this on a new WPF application

XAML

and in form

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Customer> collection = new    ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        collection.Add(new Customer());
        Dgv.ItemsSource = collection;
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Marks { get; set; }

    }
```

On running this  DataGridNumericColumn  allows first character alphabet after that it restricts.
Please tell me how to correct this problem. User Control name is WGrid.

Thanks.

[Image of datagrid. You can see character a in weight column.It occurs only on begin edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB8tZ.png)

Comment: May you add more detail about col value and show us a snapshot of the result?

Comment: I used ur code without issues.

Comment: Can You please send zip of the project you created.